# What is a "cross check"?

Tags: crew

Shortly before take-off, and again before landing, the cockpit (no way to tell whether it was the Captain or First Officer) came on over the speakers, stating:

> Flight Attendant's, prepare for take-off/landing and cross-check

What is a cross-check?

Comment: I've only heard this (outside the cockpit, instrument cross-checks happen all the time) as part of "arm slides and cross check", same thing?

Comment: @falstro I would assume so -- "Doors locked, slides armed" seems like the most obvious thing that Flight Attendants would need to cross-check.

Comment: In France, they say "armement des toboggans, vérification de la porte opposées", which could be translate as "arming slides, opposite door (cross-)check"

Answer (score 33, accepted):

[This website](http://www.askthepilot.com/how-to-speak-airline/) has the definition:

> Crosscheck is a generic term used by pilots and flight attendants
>   meaning that one person has verified the task of another. In the
>   cabin, flight attendants crosscheck one another’s stations to make
>   sure the doors are armed or disarmed as necessary.

Comment: Obviously they don't want to unduly alarm (already nervous enough) passengers by talking about _arming_ things and _slides_ and locking/securing doors, so the command is given without specifying _what_ is being crosschecked (or maybe just "_doors_"). The cabin crew knows what they're supposed to do, and whose work to (cross) check for completion.

Comment: If you watch the cabin crew after this announcement is made, you'll see them do stuff with the doors and then peer across the cabin to check that the crew member at the opposite door has done their thing correctly.

Comment: @PhilPerry On most of the flights I've been on, they've used the same formula: "Cabin crew doors flight position and cross-check, please."

Comment: I've been on many flights where the request is the "Arm doors and cross-check", usually Singapore Airlines.

Comment: Most flights I have taken in the EU have used a simple instruction to "arm slides/doors" without any cross-check references.

Comment: @jCisco: Southwest does that too, if memory serves.