# What is communicated between flight crew and cabin crew during flight?

Tags: pilots, cockpit, flight-attendant

During a typical trans-atlantic flight, can anyone list communication between flight crew and cabin crew?

I am interested in "mandatory", i.e. safety-relevant communication between the flight deck and the cabin, such as the before take-off and before landing notifications from the flight deck to the cabin crew.

What information must be communicated (by law) according to, e.g., ICAO or a major country jurisdiction?

---

Let's exclude any information regarding passengers, pax health issues, operational delays, meals, anything that is not directly safety relevant.

Comment: This question is just too broad.  There are hundreds of different scenarios.  Passengers with connections to make, weather, run out of food/drinks/, problems in the cabin, passenger ill etc etc etc etc.

Comment: While I agree that this is a *broad* question, I do think that a good list of common calls and communications could be compiled, either listing actual call ("doors cross checked") or listing a general category ("passenger meal or drink requests"). I *think* that such a list could be compiled to reasonable length appropriate for this format.

Comment: @JonathanWalters In which case, it would substantially duplicate [this question](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/11714/are-the-communications-between-captain-and-flight-attendants-normalized?rq=1)

Comment: I'll have the fish please...

Answer (score 2):

The FAA at least would seem not to have **any** requirements of communication between flight and cabin crews. However, airlines must have guidance or standard procedures for such communication. One thing I have always heard--but cannot find in any regulation--is a PA announcement to the effect of "cabin crew, prepare for takeoff;" I can only assume that all airlines have adopted this.

This is not to say that communication does not occur; quite the opposite in fact. Cabin and flight crews communicate regularly about all sorts of issues, from upcoming weather to passenger issues and operational concerns. It is only that such communication is not **required** by regulations (at least not in the United States).

Answer (score 0):

Turbulence issues such as severe weather ahead that they need to tell flight attendants to take their seats would be one.